# Cardinality Of $n^{\aleph_0}$ for cardinals $n$ up to $\aleph_0$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Considering The Continuum Hypothesis in it's most simplified form States that $|\mathbb{R}| = 2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$.

1. Is $3^{\aleph_0} = |\mathbb{R}| = 2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$?
   what about other $n\in N: n^{\aleph_0}?$ For $n=1$, it looks like $\aleph_0$ to me :) so what would it be for $n=0$ ?!

2. What if $|\mathbb{R}| = \aleph_0^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_{\aleph_0} > ... > 4^{\aleph_0} > 3^{\aleph_0} > 2^{\aleph_0} > 1^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_0$, there were countably infinite many continuums, and call $\mathbb{R}$ something like The Absolute Continuum?

PS: just learned a bit of latex to write this post plz don't judge my language. i'm more used to turing-complete universes :)

send bacon and huggies

H

Answer (score 4):

In this context, the notation $a^b$ is the size of the set of *functions* from a set of size $b$ to one of size $a$.  For example, you can check for yourself that there are exactly 8 possible functions from a set of size 3 to one of size 2.

The notation $n^{\aleph _0}$ means the number of dfferent fuctions from $\Bbb N$ to a set with $n$ elements.  We can take our set of  $n$ elements to be $\{0,1,2,\ldots ,n-1\}$.   And we can understand a function from $\Bbb N$ to $\{0,1,2,\ldots ,n-1\}$ as an infinite *sequence* of elements of $\{0,1,2,\ldots ,n-1\}$. ( In fact, this is the formal definition of “sequence”.)

It can be shown that for $n≥2$ the set of sequences is always the same size.  Here is one unusually straightforward   example. Suppose $b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4,\ldots$ is a sequence whose elements are all $0$’s and $1$’s. Then
$$b_1\cdot 2+b_2,
b_3\cdot2+b_4, \ldots$$ is a sequence whose elements are all from $\{0,1,2,3\}$, and each sequence of elements of $\{0,1,2,3\}$ similarly corresponds to exactly one sequence of elements of $\{0,1\}$.

For other $n≥2$ the situation is the same. Note that each real number between 0 and 1 usually corresponds to a single sequence of elements of $\{0,1,\ldots n-1\}$: its representation as a sequence of base-$n$ digits. (There are some exceptions, but only a few, and these don't affect the final count.)

For $n=1$ the situation is simpler. There is only one sequence:
$$1,1,1,1,1,\ldots$$ so $$1^{\aleph_0}=1.$$

For $n=0$, there are no sequences because the set of permitted elements is empty: $$0^{\aleph_0}=0.$$

It can be shown that $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0} =2^{\aleph_0}$. But $\aleph_{\aleph_0}$ (usually written $\aleph_\omega$ for technical reasons) is much, much larger, far larger than $\aleph_1$.

Comment: ok i get that $2^{\aleph_0} = 4^{\aleph_0}$ but that doesn't seem to answer $3^{\aleph_0}$. and also the cardinality of the real numbers $\Re$

Comment: The next paragraph explains this.

Comment: ok i get that $2^{\aleph_0} = 4^{\aleph_0}$ still that kind of bothers me because depending how u choose ur function u can cover all elements or not cover some elements for ex $b_0b_1b_2b_3...$ can be mapped from base 2 to base 4 with the very same digits and still have other numbers in base 4 which do not have a number from base 2 assigned to them. for ex. $(b_0b_1b_2b_3....)2$ can be mapped to $(b_0b_1b_2b_3....)4$ without even using 2 and 3 as digits so looks like base4 is bigger

Comment: Now it is time for you to stop writing and start thinking quietly. I answered your questions and gave you a lot to think about.  You cannot expect to understand it all instantly. Come back in a week if you still have questions.

Comment: the more i think the more i realize my life is a lie. gtgt sleep maybe it'll come to me in a dream lol

Comment: $\aleph_\omega$ is also provably unequal to $|\Bbb R|$, with or without the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: @J.G.This doesn't surprise me,  but I would love to read a proof...mostly to see if I would understand it :).   Been like 5 years since my set theory class and 2 years since I was a grad student actually working in higher level math

Comment: @Alan This is follows from [König's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)), and more generally $2^{\aleph_\alpha} \neq \aleph_{\omega_\alpha}$, and more...

Answer (score 0):

for qn 1, $1^{\aleph_0}=1$ and $0^{\aleph_0}=0$
for qn 2,
assume $n\geq 2$ is a natural number.
$2\leq n \leq \aleph_0$
$2^{\aleph_0}\leq n^{\aleph_0}\leq \aleph_0^{\aleph_0}\leq (2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0}$
so every element in the ineq chain is $2^{\aleph_0}$.
i don't know what $\aleph_{\aleph_0}$ is though, but it is larger than ${\aleph_1}$.

the above argument shows $2^{\aleph_0}=4^{\aleph_0}$ , but one can prove this in another way.
$4^{\aleph_0}=2^{2\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$